# Is there a Bitcoin gateway for PrestaShop with these specific features?

Tags: payment, shopping-cart-interface

[PrestaShop](http://www.prestashop.com/) is a free, secure and open source shopping cart platform.

I am searching for a PrestaShop payment processor with the following features:

1. works without without third party (save commission)
2. gives a new address to every checkout
3. automatically verifies in admin/customer after N confirmations
4. gives wallet info in admin panel

Alternatively, is there a PHP implementation with these functions to allow coding all this?

Comment: A fairly comprehensive list of Shopping Cart Interfaces is: http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Shopping_Cart_Interfaces

Answer (score 2):

Check this http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/123451-module-free-bitcoin/ it says is free and works without integrating with online payments processors

Answer (score 1):

Our Bitcoin HD module for Prestashop answer all your questions. It is based on the HD (Hierarchical Deterministic) wallet so your bitcoins are safe and no need to third party.

Notice that I am the developer of Bitcoin HD module.

Link to the module page :
https://www.motionseed.com/fr/modules-prestashop/bitcoin-paiement-prestashop

Answer (score 0):

Blockonomics [prestashop plugin](https://github.com/blockonomics/prestashop-plugin) is free and has all the above features in addition to others such as:

- Payments go directly into your wallet
- No approvals / documentation required
- Email notifications / admin panel and dashboard
- Supports all major HD wallets like mycelium, trezor, ledger